# Dividing polygon and assigning values ​proportionally (population) using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, splitting, qgis-3

I need to split several polygons (census blocks)  that contains numerical attributes (population) into smaller blocks, but assigning that data proportionally.

For example: if the splitting is made by 40/60%, and the population value is 1000, i want QGIS 3.2 to assign 400/600 proportionally to each polygon.

With the Split features function, the data is duplicated (QGIS replicates ALL the original values). I would love if there was a plugin that allows it to be made using the Split Polygon function "by hand", but I know that it is practically impossible.

[image]

The calculated field does not work.

1st step: create a calculated field ($area)

[image]

2nd step: cut the “one” polygon:

[image]

3rd step: create a calculated field (“population” * $area / “old_area”) as Virtual Field:

[image]

Result: the first result is OK (on the the polygon that was cut first), the “new_pop” value was calculated fine:

[image]

BUT the next split does not work (polygon "two"), the “new_pop” values are: 100 and 40, when should be 60 and 40. The first row is not updated.

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Does the virtual field update after saving the edits?

Comment: Yes, it does. Your instructions are ok. I'm new to GIS, and until now I thought that the commands of the field calculator operated as Excel functions (updated automatically). Thank you for you help!

Comment: Sometimes there's a bit of a lag between when you edit a feature and when the virtual field updates. It's best to save edits to be sure the `$area` function is calculated using the updated geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with Field Calculator.

- Use Field Calculator to add area of original polygon as an attribute, called "old_area".
- Split all the polygons you want to divide.
- Add a new population attribute, called "pop_new". Use Field Calculator to calculate "pop_new" as old population multiplied by the ratio of the current area to the old area.

  > "population" * $area / "old_area"

If you use a virtual field or a default field value for "pop_new" it will be automatically calculated anytime you split another polygon.

Comment: Great, easier than I thought! Thanks! The only thing that does not work is the automated calculation. When I continue splitting (after creating a virtual field as indicated), the "population" value of the original polygon is not updated, but the new polygon does.

Comment: Are you saying that when you split one polygon into two polygons, one of the two smaller polygons is updated, but one of them is not? That seems like a bug, since the `$area` value is changed. Please report it at issues.qgis.org. In the mean time, you should be able to force it to update by moving one of the vertices a little bit.

Comment: I've updated the question, can you take a look, please? To confirm if I should report it as a bug or i'm doing something wrong.